# Bullet Physics, can't get collision with static ground to work

Tags: c#, physics, collision, bullet

I'm using bullet physics in my engine and it wasn't too hard to get it integrated. The problem I am facing is that the collision system does not seem to recognize my floor plate.
I create the physics system like this:

```
var collisionConfig = new BulletSharp.DefaultCollisionConfiguration();
        PhysicsWorld = new BulletSharp.DiscreteDynamicsWorld(
            new BulletSharp.CollisionDispatcher(collisionConfig), 
            new BulletSharp.DbvtBroadphase(), 
            new BulletSharp.SequentialImpulseConstraintSolver(), 
            collisionConfig);
```

Now I add rigidbodies with cubic collision meshes (provided by bullet):

```
    public void SetCollisionBox(Vector3 center, Vector3 scale)
    {
        SetBody(new BoxShape(0.5f), center, scale);
    }
    private void SetBody(CollisionShape shape, Vector3 center, Vector3 scale)
    {
        Center = center;
        ClearBody();
        RigidBodyConstructionInfo info = new RigidBodyConstructionInfo(1, new DefaultMotionState(Matrix4.CreateTranslation(Transform.Position) + Transform.Rotation.ToMatrix4()), shape);
        Body = new RigidBody(info);

        Body.CollisionShape.LocalScaling = scale;

        GameObject.App.PhysicsWorld.AddRigidBody(Body);
    }
```

I make the floor plate static like this:

```
    public void MakeStatic()
    {
        if (Body != null)
            Body.SetMassProps(0, Vector3.Zero);
    }
```

Unfortunately no objects seems to collide with the floor plate. They just fall through.
Where is my mistake ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was the addition of matrices. I should have multiplied them. Addition caused the matrices to be in a weird state, confusing the physics engine.